# Could not use "Database.accdb"; file already in use

Tags: ms-access-2016

This message pops up if I try to Compact and Repair or when trying to save the database as another version of Access. The file is saved in my documents folder on a desktop computer at home with no mapped drives and no other users other than myself - I have tried copying the database to different folders on C: drive and D: drive and also a USB thumb drive - no matter where the database is I get the error. The permissions for the database are myself, SYSTEM, Administrators all with full control

Comment: Have tried some of the suggestions [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_access-mso_win10-mso_365hp/could-not-use-databaseaccdb-file-already-in-use/999c3fc2-d151-4c86-bd0f-5ab58f599e25?page=2)?

Virus scanner?
Run `msaccess.exe "C:\PathToYourDatabase\yourdbasename.accdb" /Compact` from Start | Run. 
Use Task Manager to look for processes w/ a lock on the file

Comment: Craig Eddy: Thanks for the link you provided - it turns out the answer to my problem was in one of the comments regarding Bitdefender (free edition) which I thought might be the problem but when i disabled Bitdefender the problem was still occurring. I just uninstalled Bitdefender and everything is working as designed.